# PHP UTF8 mail gets garbled on iPhone mail app

Tags: php, iphone, email, utf-8

I am using php internal mail function to send mail, I wrapped it up in a function which UTF8 the process, I found it online.

it works, I sent the email in the code to my GMAIL and to my EXCHANGE server, both in GMAIL and my Outlook client on my PC I get the message just right.

My iPhone is also connected to the exchange and GMAIL accounts, so I get both messages on my iPhone. the iPhone receives the GMAIL message correctly, but the EXCHANGE account shows the message with garbled gibberish text where no-latin characters are.

the example bellow sends Hebrew characters in the subject and in the body. On my iPhone, the subject gets received correctly in Hebrew, but the Hebrew parts in the body of the message are garbled.

can anyone comment on that ? maybe try it on your own setup ?

thanks,

```
<?php


function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $header = '') { 
$header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .   "\r\n"; 
mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_ . $header);  
}

$mymessage = "Hello <BR>"; 
$mymessage.= "Received: now<BR/><BR/>";
$mymessage.= "details: שלום שלום<BR/><BR/>";

mail_utf8 ("XXX@gmail.com,XXX@exchangeServer.com", "שלום", $mymessage, "my_mail", "mailer@phpmail.com");


?>
```

Comment: btw, I don't think you need the `<br />`s when sending a `text/plain` email, `PHP_EOL` would probably work better.

Comment: actually I am trying to send HTML, I just copied the wrong header in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem with iPhone and Exchange, I solved my problem using 
`Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n` and `quoted_printable_encode()`
try your code this way:

```
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from ='') { 
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
}
$mymessage = "Hello <BR>"; 
$mymessage.= "Received: now<BR/><BR/>";
$mymessage.= "details: שלום שלום<BR/><BR/>";
$mymessage = quoted_printable_encode($mymessage);

mail_utf8 ("XXX@gmail.com,XXX@exchangeServer.com", "שלום", $mymessage, "mailer@phpmail.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the message is correctly received on your gmail account through your iPhone this is probably a bug/misconfiguration on the exchange server or in the iPhone Exchange synchronisation.

The best thing to do would be to base64 encode not only the subject but the whole message: the characters base64 uses are almost always transferred correctly since the character codes are the same in US-ASCII, ISO-8859-x and UTF-8. All modern mail clients can decode base64, but it does increase the size of your message by about 33%.

```
 function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $header = '') { 
      $header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .   "\r\n" .
                 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n"; 
      mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', base64_encode($message), $header_ . $header);  
 }
```

Comment: Tried your code, GMAIL got it right,  Outlook and iPhone got all of it's body garbled now, even latin text...

Comment: I am using Thunderbird to send the messages and got the same symptoms with iPhone reading them from GMail account. In my case `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` is defined, so it looks that transfer encoding is not the root of the problem. See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0cb7a810647d9dd8 and http://forum.nuevasync.com/forum/posts/list/15/118.page

Comment: A word of warning to anyone using this: base64_encoding makes it more likely for your email to end up in the Spam/Bulk filter because a base64 encoded body is a red flag to spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - use [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). The header magic in emails is unpredictable. I've also tried playing around with it for a looong time but sooner or later, someone reported that on *his* setup (email provider or application), text is garbled or something (I send a lot of emails in czech, so working UTF is a priority).

Use Swift Mailer and save yourself some nerves. It's fast to setup and learn and works great.

Comment: An mail wrapper like the one you provided or PHPMailer would work, but isn't a solution to this specific problem. Especially if the code wholly works refactoring to work with a wrapper it might be more work than just fixing the bug.

Comment: I tried PHPMAILER, another wrapper, it sent the mail and I got the exact same result... still garbled...

Comment: @Moshe Marciano, In that case I can't help you much more, I don't have much experience with iProducts and precisely zero experience with their internals...

Comment: After benchmarking of Swift Mailer, I've stopped it's use, it takes too much ressources for simple stuff.